# Mac OneDrive migration extremely slow - 100 mb/hour

Tags: mac, backup, file-transfer, onedrive, cloud-storage

I've finally gotten around to Cloud storage (OneDrive), and am adding all the files on my 2019 MacBook Pro to the OneDrive folder. It is about 70 GB worth of data and contains 140,000 files.

The initial few files uploaded quickly, but now its only uploading about 100 MB per hour and it looks like the process will take many days to complete. The inefficiency of this transfer process is astonishing to me so far, especially given OneDrive allows for a whole terabyte of storage.

- Files On-Demand is turned on
- I've given OneDrive full disk access in Privacy Settings
- Very few applications are running in the background
- Speed test: 98.4 Mb/s download, 97.1 Mb/s upload, bufferbloat idle is 32ms, downloading is 183 ms, uploading is 170 ms.

The upload seems to be working in batches - maybe 20-30 files at once, and then it just pauses for minutes at a time. Is there any advice on how to fix this speed issue? Most online solutions that recommend what my first three bullets (above) have already done, and I'm not sure what else to do. Really disappointed with the efficiency of OneDrive so far.

**It worked well with 25 GB in 1000 files, but something about the large number of files I'm uploading now (140,000, even though its only 70 GB total) is making OneDrive completely unusable.**

Update: It suggests [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/invalid-file-names-and-file-types-in-onedrive-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#synctoomany) that OneDrive may not be optimized for >100,000 files, but surely being **this** slow must be the result of another issue? At the current rate, the sync would take >2 months.

Comment: Few consumer connections are the same speed in both directions, 100mbps down would normally have only 10mbps up. The second main consumer issue is bufferbloat, especially over wifi. Run speedtests at https://dslreports.com & report back what they say.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't think speed is the issue: I did a 25 GB upload yesterday with fewer files, and it was fine. OneDrive seemed to start struggling when I had a large number of files (100,000+), even if they are small. Speed test results: 98.4 Mb/s download, 97.1 Mb/s upload, bufferbloat idle is 32ms, downloading is 183 ms, uploading is 170 ms.

Comment: OneDrive has an option to throttle. Do you have 'Do Not Throttle' set in settings/options? It's under the Network tab, for upload and download. Alternatively, can you map a network drive? AFAIK the slowness can be caused by the sync check.

Comment: @spikey_richie Both my Upload Rate and Download Rate are set at "Don't limit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up attempting to transfer my files to OneDrive in batches. About 5,000-10,000 files at a time. I'm through about 3 out of 10 total batches, and though its slow, its not nearly as slow as before (maybe a few hours per batch).

It appears that the time required for the file transfer doesn't increase linearly with the number of files, but perhaps more quadratically. This is odd to me, but the batching provided a temporary fix.

I'll post updates to this answer as I finish transferring the batches and then observe performance of OneDrive overall after all my files have been transferred and synced.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. I tried to troubleshoot for months. I figured out it was my home network connection. They sent me this: https://www.dwthacker.com/finding-and-setting-mtu-on-mac. You can either adjust the MTU on the Mac or in the router settings (if your router has a setting for MTU). Once I changed my MTU down from 5000 OneDrive resumed uploading as normal.